# PHP system command returning no output

Tags: php, windows

I am on Windows 10 and have the following PHP code:

```
<?php

system("php -v");

?>
```

It is expected to output my PHP version as it does when I run `php -v` in my command prompt:

```
PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 11 2022 08:55:59) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

However, it is not giving any output at all.

Can someone guide me on how to fix this? Other commands such as `python --version` are returning the appropriate output through the `system` function, only `php -v` has this behavior.

**UPDATE:** I just tried `system(".\~\..\..\xampp\php\php.exe -v");` so it uses the exact path of the PHP executable but still no luck. Again, running the same command in the command prompt returns the desired output for some reason.

**UPDATE 2:** Trying the update suggested by @hanshenrik seems to generate the following error: `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. string(31) "operable program or batch file."`. I do have PHP in my path and using `php -v` in a normal command prompt in any directory gives me the relevant results, it's just that the `system` or (recently tested) `passthru` commands in PHP are not getting it to execute.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250393/discussion-on-question-by-xybox-php-system-command-returning-no-output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like a "PATH environment variable problem" for unknown reasons, your PHP's PATH does not include `C:\xampp\php` , while your cmd's PATH does include it.

you can ensure it's there at runtime by doing

```
setenv("PATH",getenv("PATH").PATH_SEPARATOR."C:\\xampp\\php");
```

this is a simple approach and should work in the real world, but is kind-of non-optimal because it risks duplicating the path. a "proper" solution to adding the path would probably be something like (untested)

```php
if(!in_array("C:\\xampp\\php",explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, getenv("PATH")), true){
    setenv("PATH",getenv("PATH").PATH_SEPARATOR."C:\\xampp\\php");
}
```